# jQuery click event behaves differently with live function in Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery

Using the event click with live function leads to strange behavior when using Firefox*.
With live in Firefox, click is triggered when right-clicking also! The same does not happen in Internet Explorer 7 neither in Google Chrome.

Example:

- [Without live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click), go to demo and try right clicking
  the paragraphs. A dialog menu should
  appear.
- [With live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), go to demo and try right
  clicking "Click me!". Now both dialog
  menu and "Another paragraph" appear.

*tested with firefox 3.5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, that is a known issue (bug?). You can easily work around it by testing which button was clicked as follows:

```
$('a.foo').live("click", function(e) { 
    if (e.button == 0) { // 0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right 
        //left button was clicked
    } else {
        //other button was clicked (do nothing?)
        //return false or e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

you might prefer using a `switch` depending on your specific requirements, but generally you would probably just want to do nothing (or or simply return) if any button other than the left button is clicked, as above:

```
    $('a.foo').live("click", function(e) {
        switch(e.button) {
            case 0 : alert('Left button was clicked');break;
            default: return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a known "bug", you could potentially query the event object after attaching the click handler ( which gets attached to the document ) and see if its a right click, otherwise manually attach the click handler after you manipulate the DOM.

After looking it up, e.button is the property you want to query:

```
.live('click', function(e){

if ( e.button == 2 ) return false; // exit if right clicking

// normal action

});
```

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489817/jquery-liveclick-firing-for-right-click/1489893#1489893): if you don't mind changing the jQuery source a bit, adding a single line in the `liveHandler()` works around the problem entirely.