# How to enable click event from <a> inside a jQuery's toggle() method?

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-click-event

I've a tree menu. The last `<li>` element from this menu contains an `<a>` element.

I'm using the jQuery `toggle()` method.

I know that `toggle()` contains an `e.preventDefault()` by default.

What I wanna do is give back the click event to the `<a>` element.

Could you pls help?

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        Item1
        <ul style="display: none">
            <li>
                subItem1
                <ul style="display: none">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
                    </li>     
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".menu li").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).children().slideDown();
    },

    function() {
        $(this).children().slideUp(); 
    }
);
```

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzy48/

Comment: Have you tried what this question suggests? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-enable-default-after-event-preventdefault

Answer (score 1):

You were missing some closing tags.

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzy48/2/).

```
$(".menu li").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Using the `on()` method you have more control over your functionality. What you need is the [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method: it prevents the click event from bubbling up the dom tree to a parent `li` which would slide-toggle it.

Also by filtering the children of the clicked `li` to only `ul`'s you are more explicit in what you want to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version to Flauwekeul's one, using `.on()` event delegation:

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'li', function(event){
    if (event.target != this) {
     return;//dont want bubbled up events
    }
    $(event.target).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

See it in **http://jsfiddle.net/fzy48/5/**

The advantage of using event delegation is we just attach one event handler(in the parent `.menu` element), instead of one event handler per `li` element.