# Mouse Scrolling and other button clicks is not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, responsive-design

I am working with a website which needs fully responsive for the devices. I am testing it iPhone 5. Mouse wheel scroll and buttons clicks is not working when I am testing with iPhone. But everything is working fine when I am testing with online iPhone simulators.

**N. B.** Actually, I can't post code here. Because, I can't guess what is the problem there.

Comment: I-Phones have their own events. Are you listening on them? E.g. they have no click event AFAIK.

Comment: @user2820379, I see!! Can you give me some events listening tuts for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Answer (score 0):

Your website may be preventing the default action for touch events which would prevent scrolling. Although I can not say more without seeing the actual code, here is a possible solution to your dilemma: [How to unbind a listener that is calling event.preventDefault() (using jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-enable-default-after-event-preventdefault). Essentially you need to restore the default actions that occur after touching the screen.