# Do preventDefault and then do default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, single-page-application

I have a requirement in a single page application project, where I need to change a page's section when I click on a anchor tag based on the provided `href` attribute. Something like this:

```
<a class="page-click" href="#showPeople/1">Open</a>
```

This anchor is in a popup on that page. So, whenever I click on this anchor tag, the anchor should close the popup and change the window location to

```
http://www.example.com/#showPeople/1
```

Now, the anchor is changing the url (*which is by default*) but not closing the popup.

When I researched I found that for anchors, I should use `e.preventDefault()` to remove default behavior. But in my case, I need both default behavior as well as the custom behavior (*closing the popup*).

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895998/1577396) which has similar requirement but the thing is that I am attaching event dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click', '.page-click', function (e) {
     // e.preventDefault();
     // code here
});
```

and even if I somehow succeeded to `unbind` the event from that specific clicked anchor, the anchor will not close the popup, when the user opens the popup again (*since the registered event has been removed*).

Comment: where is your popup here?

Comment: [Here is one way](https://gist.github.com/humbleRumble/6b2ff1b406bdac61694c). Or am I missing the mark?

Comment: @JqueryKing Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te8kw96n/). I am not sure how to include backbone to show single page application behavior though.

Comment: @TinyGiant At a glance, I thought it should work but it is actually creating a recursive effect.

Comment: I guess then you would have to set a variable and check whether it is true before executing the function (including the preventDefault)

Comment: just close popup in your callback **do not prevent default action** and it will be the solution

Comment: @YarikKotsur nice but that means I need to write closepopup function in all those different callbacks. (_there are many, I will go with this if there is no better way_)

Comment: Check that link again. It should work now.

Comment: @Mr_Green maybe this can help https://gist.github.com/shults/4968e851b2cb2931cd89

Comment: @TinyGiant I really like your idea. but is somehow not triggering the click event again. I mean this code is not triggering:  `$(this).click()`.

Comment: try `e.target` instead of `this`

Comment: @TinyGiant I checked `this` is a anchor element only.

Comment: Well, I'm heading to bed for the night. If you haven't figured it out by morning, I'll work on it some more.

Comment: @TinyGiant sure np. thanks for giving the thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('active');
});
$(document).on('click', 'a.page-click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.popup').hide('fast', function() { 
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + $this.attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I hate to hardcode the url but I think there is no other way around.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will work for you but once I had a requirement of keeping a html tag as `<a href="#">Demo</a>`but I just wanted it as a placeholder and the requirement was not to change url in address bar.I did following

```
$('a').click(function() {
    // below line prevents the 'href' from followed.
    return false;
});
```

I guess you can try this.