# Allow bootstrap modal to be closed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am sending some information from my modal to my php server. Until the php server does not respond, I do not want the modal being closed in any way (clicking outside, pressing ESC, clicking on close buttons etc). So I have used the following code:

```
$('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Once the server has responded, how can I revert to the default behaviour of the modal? I tried the following but it does not work:

```
$('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   return true;
});
```

Comment: hey you can get some info here abiut this preventDefault method
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-unbind-a-listener-that-is-calling-event-preventdefault-using-jquery

Comment: did you try to use $('#yourModal').modal({'backdrop': 'static'}) and closing with jquery when you get response from server-side;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this approach?
Set a variable `submitting` to true before you execute the ajax request and back to false after it's done.

```
$('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (submitting) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```