# Disable jquery from closing a div when RIGHT clicking inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

Okay, so I have a `div` that pops up when it is opened. When the `div` is open (showing) when you click anywhere in the window that ISN'T the `div` itself, it closes the `div`. When I click IN the pop out div it stays open - as should) All that works...

However when I RIGHT-CLICK inside the div, `JQuery` treats it as if it was a click outside of the div and closes it --> I don't want this to happen. I want it to stay open the same way it does when you left click inside of it.

Here is the code.

**NOTE: THIS CODE IS WORKING. HOWEVER I NEED TO ADD SOMETHING TO STOP THE ISSUE STATED ABOVE.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#showpopup").click(function( e ) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
       $("#mainpopout").show();
    });

    $("#actualpopout").on('click',function( e ){
         e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).on('click', function( e ) {
       if( e.target.id != 'actualpopout' ){
           $("#mainpopout").hide();
           document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
       }   
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I pulled this straight out of my PHP file, hence the back slashes.

Comment: can u share a fiddle link??

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yKhfP/58/ - I just noticed this is only an issue in Firefox

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery live('click') firing for right-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489817/jquery-liveclick-firing-for-right-click)

Comment: Wow. I searched and couldn't find an answer on the site, however this is it... Thanks!!